# Microsoft Graph API - Request photo from user by size

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get user photos with a specific size.
Reading GraphAPI Docs my request should look like this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photos/48x48/$value

This is working perfectly fine and I'm getting the photo in my desired size. Unfortunately it is only working for 'me' and not for other users. For example the request

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{email}/photos/64x64/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Bemail%7D/photos/64x64/$value)

returns the image in its full resolution. Is this a Graph API bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is [currently a known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups) with accessing group photos using application permissions and [its documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups). So it will work for delegated permissions only.